# How do I create a slef join or calculated field in powerbi that show the inventory of a DC and sum all store inventory belong to that DC

Tags: powerbi, dax

The table looks like this:

| Location ID | Location Type | Inventory | Supporting DC ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | DC | 100 | 0 |
| 2 | Store | 50 | 1 |
| 3 | DC | 75 | 0 |
| 4 | Store | 120 | 3 |
| 5 | DC | 90 | 0 |
| 6 | Store | 60 | 1 |
| 7 | DC | 110 | 0 |
| 8 | Store | 40 | 7 |
| 9 | DC | 85 | 0 |
| 10 | Store | 70 | 3 |

The matrix I want to display is like this:

| Location ID | DC Inventory | Total Store Inventory |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 110 |
| 3 | 75 | 190 |
| 5 | 90 | 0 |
| 7 | 110 | 40 |
| 9 | 85 | 0 |

Because all stores belonging to DC #1 are #2 and #6 the total inventory is 110, all stores belonging to DC #3 are #4 and #10, and the total inventory is 190... so on and so forth.

can anyone help me with this? I am pretty newbie on Power-BI, not sure how I can approach the result.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a **Measure** similar to:

```
Total Store Inventory = 
  var result = 
    CALCULATE(
      SUM(YourTable[Inventory]),
      ALL(YourTable),
      YourTable[Supporting DC ID] in DISTINCT(YourTable[Location ID])
    )
  return result
```